# SQL Server CPU time is greater than elapsed time (MAXDOP 1)

Tags: sql-server

I understood that "CPU Time" can be higher than "Elapsed Time" when processed in parallel.

But when I performed a query using `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` (to avoid parallelism), "Cpu time" is greater than "Elapsed Time" of "SQL Server Execution Times".

When is the "Cpu time" greater than "Elapsed Time" with the query using `OPTION(MAXDOP 1)`?

I used the `AdventureWorks` database provided by SQL Server. I wrote `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` in the query.

```
USE AdventureWorks

SELECT 
    p.BusinessEntityID, p.firstname, p.MiddleName, p.LastName, pp.PhoneNumber
FROM 
    Person.Person AS p 
INNER JOIN 
    Person.PersonPhone AS pp ON p.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID
WHERE 
    p.BusinessEntityID > 100
ORDER BY 
    p.BusinessEntityID DESC
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Unexpectedly, "CPU time" was greater than "Elapsed time".

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 125 ms,  elapsed time = 118 ms.
```

Comment: More than 1 CPU even if the execution didn't go parallel? Bet it is manager CPU and execution CPU.

Comment: @JBrooks Sorry. Could you explain manager and execution CPU? Thank you.